# Xamarin Forms : Share and Invite

Tags: xamarin.forms

These days I started working on Xamarin a cross platform tool.I am using Xamarin Forms and have almost nearby completion of my project except some challenges I am facing and need to resolve. Please do help me as how to achieve it using Xamarin forms.

a) As per the requirement I wanted to give an option of "Share And Invite" but I did not find any cross platform API to do that, please shed some light on it.

b) I wanted to integrate an option of InApp analytics rather than Google analytics, for e.g. I wanted to know the action being performed by user on a certai  page like how many times he is logging in or signout of application etc..

Any help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

for the first question (If I have understand your problem) I think you can take a look to this plugin

[Share plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin)

for the second, maybe Insight could help you

[Xamarin Insight](https://insights.xamarin.com/login)

Comment: I suggest to you to try also with the forums.xamarin.com